# how to create kannada webpages in html ..?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new to developing websites for  kannada font. please help me, how to make web pages in html for displaying kannada fonts.

my project will include:

1) basic notes (like pdf) in kannada. but i have to display by webpage not in pdf.
2) the end-user will be very poor in computer. so it should not be include more trouble to him.
3)its a dynamic website so, it should also support for back end with php/mysql..

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your font issue.
This is the ordinary method to import fonts to your site.

```
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/notosanskannada.css);
body { font-family: "Noto Sans Kannada", sans-serif;}
</style>
```